# Regex to match = followed by a newline so they both be deleted

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, regular-expression, newlines

I am working with the raw source content of a mail.app message in OSX, but results it gives me the text in quoted printable MIME Email encoding. so I need to remove all those strange characters to get the correct HTML.

Here is an example:

```
<p style=3D"margin:1em 0 3px 0;">
<a name=3D"1" style=3D"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:1=
8px;" href=3D"http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/WwwhatsNew/~3/8BdOd-xRTU4/?utm=
_source=3Dfeedburner&amp;utm_medium=3Demail">Hyundai ya ofrece manuales de =
los coches con Realidad Aumentada</a>
</p>
```

Here I have =CRLF and =3D

I know how to replace all of this characters =C3=A1 =C3=A9 =C3=AD =C3=B3 =C3=BA =C3=81 =C3=89 =C3=8D =C3=93 =C3=9A =C3=B1 =C3=91 =3D =f

I just need to delete this =CRLF or '=' followed by a newline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why reinvent the wheel?  `qprint` already exists:

> Description-en: encoder and decoder for quoted-printable encoding
>
> Qprint is a command-line program that can encode or decode files
>   from/to quoted-printable encoding (RFC1521). It can work with both
>   text and binary data.
>
> Homepage: http://www.fourmilab.ch/webtools/qprint/

Sample input:

```
$ cat nadir.txt 
<p style=3D"margin:1em 0 3px 0;">
<a name=3D"1" style=3D"font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:1=
8px;" href=3D"http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/WwwhatsNew/~3/8BdOd-xRTU4/?utm=
_source=3Dfeedburner&amp;utm_medium=3Demail">Hyundai ya ofrece manuales de =
los coches con Realidad Aumentada</a>
</p>
```

Sample output:

```
$ qprint -d nadir.txt 
<p style="margin:1em 0 3px 0;">
<a name="1" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;" href="http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/WwwhatsNew/~3/8BdOd-xRTU4/?utm_source=feedburner&amp;utm_medium=email">Hyundai ya ofrece manuales de los coches con Realidad Aumentada</a>
</p>
```

`qprint` is available pre-packaged for most linux distros.

There are also several perl modules for encoding & decoding quoted-printable text, including `MIME::QuotedPrint` and `PerlIO::via::QuotedPrint`.   No doubt, a quick google search would also reveal QP libraries for python and other languages.